# If user is logged disable something

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to disable something (div) in HTML after user is logged.

```
<?php if($this->config->item('registration') == "1" && is_logged()) { ?>
```

This php code declare if users are logged in. I need javascript or something which says if `<?php if($this->config->item('registration') == "1" && is_logged()) { ?>` do not display div named "homepage".

Is that possible?

Comment: don't disable client-side. someone could fiddle with the DOM and re-enable it. If you don't want something to show up for a particular user/type of user, just don't output that stuff in the first place.

Comment: Have PHP spit out some JS `$('#bla').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php if($this->config->item('registration') == "1" && is_logged()) { ?>
    <div id="homepage">your content....</div>
<?}?>
```